# Can someone explain how this function work? randoms.Sort((x, y) => rnd.Next(-1, 1));

Tags: c#

I have this code and I *don't understand* the line

```
randoms.Sort((x, y) => rnd.Next(-1, 1));
```

This is the code:

```
static Random rnd = new Random();

private int[] Generate4Dir()
{
    List<int> randoms = new List<int>(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        randoms.Add(i + 1);
    }

    randoms.Sort((x, y) => rnd.Next(-1, 1));

    return randoms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Where is `rnd` defined?

Comment: im sorry its the first line befor the function

Comment: what you asked can be found on the Microsoft docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.8#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: To be honest this code *doesn’t* work great. It’s attempting to shuffle an array but (a) there are more efficient implementations, and (b) this implementation breaks the preconditions of the `Sort` functions, and it’s therefore not at all guaranteed that the result is uniformly shuffled. Don’t use this, use a proper shuffle algorithm.

Comment: It doesn't. It violates the rules for a sorting function. This code is wrong.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand `Enumerable.Sort()`? The lambda expression? `Random.Next()`?

Comment: `return randoms.OrderBy(item => rnd.Next(-1, 1)).ToArray();` since `OrderBy` (unlike `Sort`) computes `rnd.Next(-1, 1)` just *once* for each item

Comment: what is it that you are actually after? an explanation of what its doing or is there something wrong with it? What is the overall outcome you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

```
randoms.Sort((x, y) => rnd.Next(-1, 1));
```

means `Sort` `randoms` list, while *comparing* items (`x` and `y`) by the rule `rnd.Next(-1, 1)`, so that

- if `rnd.Next(-1, 1) < 0`  then it means `x < y`
- if `rnd.Next(-1, 1) == 0` then it means `x == y`
- if `rnd.Next(-1, 1) > 0`  then it means `x > y`

However, this implementation *breaks* `Sort` rules. It may well appear (since `rnd.Next(-1, 1)` returns *random value*) that
`a > b > c > a` (*intransitivity*). You can implement the idea in a correct way with a help of *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  // static: we don't use "this"
  private static int[] Generate4Dir() {
    return Enumerable
      .Range(1, 4)                      // 4 items starting from 1: 1, 2, 3, 4
      .OrderBy(item => rnd.Next(-1, 1)) // ordered by rnd.Next(-1, 1) criterium
      .ToArray();                       // materialized as an array
  }
```

Note, that `OrderBy` computes `rnd.Next(-1, 1)` for each item and only then orders them. Finally, a *much better* code is standard
shuffle alrgorithm implementation, say [Fisher–Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle, which is

1. Faster `O(n)` vs. `O(n * log(n))`
2. Doesn't want additional space: we can create the array and then shuffle it in place
3. Doesn't rely on `OrderBy` implementation

Comment: The `OrderBy` documentation doesn’t actually explicitly say that each key is only computed once. On the other hand, the documentation also doesn’t list any preconditions for the key selector (but neither does that for `List.Sort`). *Still* on the other hand, stably sorting an array of keys [-1, 0, 1] is bound to perform an *extremely poor* sort, because many elements will stay in order. This can be improved by simply using `rnd.Next()` … but a proper shuffle is of course guaranteed to work just as good, and will be vastly more efficient both in terms of runtime and space requirement.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I totally agree with you: why should we re-invent the wheel, i.e. Fisher-Yates algorithm which is faster `O(n)` vs. `O(n * log(n))` doesn't want additional space (we can create an array and shuffle it without lists), and, finally, doesn't rely on `OrderBy` implementation.

Comment: That `rnd.Next(-1, 1)` could never return a 1, could it since the upper value is exclusive?

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look what you got here:

```
randoms.Sort((x, y) => rnd.Next(-1, 1));
```

You perform a `Sort()` on a List.

```
randoms.Sort(   );
```

You send a Lambda-Expression into `Sort()`.

```
(x, y) => rnd.Next(-1, 1)
```

This Lambda-Expression is an "on-the-fly"-method-definition. You could also create a simple method in you code. This does the same:

```
static void Main()
{
    // your code...
    randoms.Sort(SortAlgorithm);
}

static Random random = new Random();
public static int SortAlgorithm(int x, int y)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Checking how to sort {x} and {y}")
    return random.Next(-1, 1);
}
```

Your "Algorithm" is to radomly choose that two numbers are smaller/bigger/equal (-1, 1, 0) to each other.

```
random.Next(-1, 1)
```